# Change the WordPress from address

Tags: email

I've taken over a site, and have found the from address for the emails (eg password reminders) are coming from the wrong address.

How can I change the from address to the correct email?

The correct address is set in the settings -> General -> Email Address

The email address that the emails are coming from is one of the administrators.

Comment: the email address is already not the standard one.  i've tried to force it using the answers in that "duplicate" - not working.  what else could it be?

Comment: I'v tried changing the first admin users email address in the DB - it doesn't change the from address